# How can we update nested projects in master project

Tags: ms-project, tools, ms-project-2007, project-server

When we open 1 project from MS Project Server , then we can update it easy and fetch changes and publish again to MSPS.

But when we have many project and programs that embedded them in 1 Master project and click on  update. This is not work.

please help me to update many projects and programs in MSPS 2007.

Answer (score 2):

My memory is 7 years old, but If I remember right, you could open each of the rolled up project in the Master project. And then Update. It most certainly updates all the projects.

Comment: but the nested project not updated